# Error while installing mysql database for new ruby app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a total newbie, trying to setup all the components needed to be learn RoR but while installing mysql I am getting this message in the terminal: 
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install

Anyone know what should I do? Thanks

Comment: can you run `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'` and post the full error report here?

Comment: also what operating system are you running?

Comment: current directory: /Users/angelosmouzakitis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: /Users/angelosmouzakitis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2

Comment: I am at Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Trying to create a new rails app and it fails. Asks me to install some other gems through bundle install. When I do it, this error appears: An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'` succeeds before bundling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql2 on your system before you can install the gem. On OSX you can do this via homebrew.

To install homebrew:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

To make sure homebrew is properly installed:

```
brew doctor
```

To install mysql:

```
brew install mysql
```

Then try your gem installation again and it should work:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.5'
```

Comment: Brew works fine. but when I install mysql2, this error appears: Error: No available formula with the name "mysql2" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:
current directory: /Users/angelosmouzakitis/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/ext/mysql2

Comment: try just `brew install mysql`

Comment: Is your mysql server running locally? This shouldn't be a problem though.

Comment: yeah to be honest, i'm stumped. did you install xcode?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dependent libraries `mysql-client` and `libmysqlclient-dev`
Command for Ubuntu machine

`sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Just to make sure, you might also want to try removing your Gemfile.lock and then re-running bundle install once all dependent libraries get installed.